# Passing Addition parameter to IControllerFactory.CreateController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mef

I am using MEF to dynamically load controllers in an MVC3 app.
In the export metadata I am specifying two meta data constraints

```
EX:
    [ExportMetadata("controllerName", "APSR")]
    [ExportMetadata("controllerVersion", "1.0.0.0")]
```

In my "main" mvc app, I am using a RedirectToAction method (In reponse to a user click on a dropdown)

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Models.HomeViewModel selected)
    {
        //ViewData.Add("Version", selected.AvailableWorkflows[int.Parse(selected.SelectedWorkflow)].Version);
        return RedirectToAction("Create", selected.AvailableWorkflows[int.Parse(selected.SelectedWorkflow)].Controller);
    }
```

**How can I pass the desired version number to my Controller factory?** Since the IControllerFactory.CreateController method only excepts to paramters:

```
IController IControllerFactory.CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you need some additional route data, and reading that when creating your controller.

For instance, I could define a route as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "APSR_Create",
  "/apsr/{version}/create",
  new {
    controller = "APSR",
    action = "Create",
    version = "1.0.0.0"
  });
```

Now, when I create an instance of my controller, I can grab that version item from the `RequestContext.RouteData` collection:

```
  public IController IControllerFactory.CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
  {
    string version = requestContext.RouteData["version"];

    // Create instance using metadata lookup...
  }
```

You just need to ensure that you are passing the version as an argument to the route.

```
  return RedirectToAction(
    "Create", 
    new { version = selected.AvailableWorkflows[int.Parse(selected.SelectedWorkflow)].Version });
```